# How to pick videos only in ELCImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using ELCImagePickerCotroller from https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

How can I use it to display only videos?

Comment: if you decide to vote down the question please mention a reason.

Comment: i will suggest you to look in issue(closed) section of this git, may be you will find an answer. if no then you can raise a issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import in you .m

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

and in your method

```
ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];
    elcPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It has the same usage with UIImagePickerController.

```
ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];
elcPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```